# Assigning elements of one array to an elements of a 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

For this piece of my project, I have to assign elements of one dynamically allocated array to another part of a dynamically allocated 2D array. I've researched and read but cannot find anything relating to my question.

When I attempt to run the program it only assigns one value to every element on the "load space" of every truck. I appreciate any help and or suggestions. I'm not allowed to use the array library. Thank you for your time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int* initializePackages(int &numPackages);
void printArray(int* arr, int size);
void shufflePackages(int* packages, int size);
int** createTrucks(int &numTrucks);
void printTrucks(int** arr, int size);
void loadTrucks(int** trucks, int* packages, int numTrucks, int numPackages);

int main()
{
    int numPackages; //receives the passed in values from initializePackages.
    int numTrucks;  //receives the passed in values from createTrucks.

    srand(time(0)); //Seed the random function with the time clock.

    int* iPackages = initializePackages(numPackages);
    cout << "\nSorted Packages: \n";
    printArray(iPackages, numPackages);

    shufflePackages(iPackages, numPackages);
    cout << "\n\nShuffled Packages: \n";
    printArray(iPackages, numPackages);

    int** iTrucks = createTrucks(numTrucks);
    cout << "\n\nTrucks: \n";
    printTrucks(iTrucks, numTrucks);

    cout << "\nLoaded Trucks: \n";
    loadTrucks(iTrucks, iPackages, numTrucks, numPackages);
    printTrucks(iTrucks, numTrucks);

}

int* initializePackages(int &numPackages)
{

    int* packages = 0; //returning the pointer from initializePackages.
    numPackages = 0;  //to pass the number of packages to main.

    cout << "Enter the number of packages to be loaded (between 60 and 500):  " << endl;
    while(numPackages < 60 || numPackages > 500){
        cin >> numPackages; //takes in the number of packages to be assigned.
    }

    packages = new int[numPackages]; //dynamically allocates an array of packages of based on the value of numPackages.

    for(int i=0; i < numPackages; i++){   //initializes the array with sequential values specified by numPackages.
        *(packages + i) = i +1;
    }

    return packages;
}

void printArray(int* arr, int size)
{
    for(int count = 0; count < size; count ++){
        cout << arr[count] << ((count + 1) % 20 ? " " : "\n"); //Accesses the array and prints out 20 elements per line.
    }
}

void shufflePackages(int* packages, int size)
{
    int j;      //additional variable to utilize as a swap variable.
    int temp;  //place holder variable.

    for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++){  //for loop to iterate through the shuffle sequence.
        j = rand() % size;           //selects random spot in the array to begin shuffling
        temp = packages[i];         //assigns a place holder variable to the initial value
        packages[i] = packages[j]; //empty packages[i] element is now assigned the value from the packages[j] element
        packages[j]=temp;         //packages[j] element is now assigned the initial value originally assigned to the place holder variable
    }
}

int** createTrucks(int &numTrucks)
{
        numTrucks = 0;


        cout << "\nEnter the number of trucks to be loaded (between 3 and 25):  "  << endl;
        while(numTrucks < 3 || numTrucks > 25){    //specifies the parameters for the number of trucks
                cin >> numTrucks;
        }

        int** trucks = new int* [numTrucks];    //dynamically allocates an array based on number of trucks.

        for(int i = 0; i < numTrucks; i++){   //accesses the truck array and assigns a number to each truck.
            trucks[i] = new int[20];         //dynamically allocates an array of 20 elements

            for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){   //initializes the truck's available load space with zeros.
                trucks[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

    return trucks;
}


void printTrucks(int** arr, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){   //loop to print out the trucks and number. "Truck #: "
        cout << "Truck " << i + 1 << ": ";

        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){ //loop prints out the available load space of the truck's trailer.
            cout << " " << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n"; //Starts a new line of truck and load space to be printed.
    }
}

void loadTrucks(int** trucks, int* packages, int numTrucks, int numPackages)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < numTrucks; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k < numPackages; k++){
                trucks[i][j] = packages[k];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take another look at your loadTrucks function, are you sure you meant to use a triple nested loop there?

Comment: I wanted to use a triple nested loop to be able to access the 2nd part of the 2D array while also being able to access the packages array and assign it to the 2nd part of the 2D array.

Comment: The loop sets trucks[i][j] to packages[0], then it sets it to packages[1], etc. This repeats until every element of trucks is set to the last element of packages. You will need to revise this to get it working.

Comment: Ok so it actually does iterate through my entire array like its supposed to, it just doesn't assign each value to it. I'm trying to get the packages to assign to the each element.

Comment: So how do I get it to loop through to where each element is assigned ?